# Spring MVC 4.1 ModelAndView constructor not working well

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, tomcat, model

I had a Spring MVC project developed in Spring MVC 3.2 and running in Tomcat 7, I just had migrated it to Spring MVC 4.1 and Tomcat 8 to support newer business requirement.

As we have some package reorganised such include domain object layer have to change to other package name such from com.longz.ozssc.mac.generated.domain to com.longz.ozssc.mac.generated.domain.nb. After I changed the package, I found my spring form submission not work, as the form object is still link to previous domain object.

I tried to update my MVC controller to set the model to newer package object by following code:

```
 @RequestMapping("/newFirm")
 public ModelAndView newFirm(@ModelAttribute("firm") Firm firm, BindingResult result, Model model) throws Exception {

   ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("firm/editFirm.jsp","firm",new com.longz.ozssc.mac.generated.domain.nb.Firm());
   mav.addObject("newFlag", true);
   return mav;
 }
```

When I tried to retrieve my model class from JSP,

```
    <form:form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/saveFirm" method="POST" modelAttribute="firm">
    <% System.out.println("ModelAttribute = |" + pageContext.findAttribute("firm")+'|'); %>
```

JSP print out as:

```
ModelAttribute = |com.longz.ozssc.mac.generated.domain.Firm[ firmAbn=null ]|
```

Seems when Tomcat 8 server do the JSP compiling is still refer to my previous Model Object, and not refer to my new ModelAndView was defined in my controller.

This issue will cause seriously result, as all fields' value (in spring form) will bind to wrong model object (com.longz.ozssc.mac.generated.domain.Firm), and that object is not accessible anymore.

Any one has idea about this issue please advise.

Appreciate!

**Edit**

More details about the model set and POST process in form:

Set up and check from JSP.

```
 <form:form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/saveFirm" method="POST" modelAttribute="firm">
 <% System.out.println("ModelAttribute = |" + pageContext.findAttribute("firm")+'|'); %>
```

Submit form by standardised spring-dojo:

```
        <span class="inputbutton"><input class="savebutton" id="save" type="submit" value="<fmt:message key="navigation.save"/>"/></span>
        <script type="text/javascript">Spring.addDecoration(new Spring.ValidateAllDecoration({elementId:'save', event:'onclick'}));</script>
```

This code working in my other version of Spring MVC3.2. The issue is form binding to wrong object.

Comment: Are you sure that your application is correctly redeployed? First thing I would do in this situation would be cleaning Tomcat just to make sure you're not actually using some old versions of your classes.

Comment: Yeah. I removed whole directory & *.war file from my Tomcata deploy folder under $CATALINA_HOME/webapps and copy newly built *.war file restart Tomcat server again. From my browser, I cleaned all cached and fresh load everything. The issue is still here.

Comment: And have you tried deleting contents of $CATALINA_HOME/work directory? Tomcat keeps some temporary stuff there ... other than that I don't really know what else could be causing this, sorry :(

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I had removed work folder from $CATALINA_HOME, and then tested, seems nothing change. Next Step, I probably need a better JSP editor that can do the semantics check as well. I am using STS 3.6.2, it is good for spring MVC, but seems the JSP editor only support syntaxes check without any semantics check at all. i.e. when we use the spring form element, editor only check every input/select element has to have path variable here, but it never check the path variable how to link to a form object, or link to which form model object. Any idea about it?

Comment: Not really. I'm using IntelliJ which is probably the best at this sort of stuff but even it doesn't check the path attributes against modelAttribute. By the way one more thing I noticed. You are refering to Firm object in your model attribute and then to nb.firm in your model and view constructor using fully qualified name. Do those refer to the same classes?

Comment: Silly question but in your controller code, Firm firm does it reference the correct package/location of the model? Because if it is bindingb to wrong model then issue can only be in that you are still telling it to bind to old inaccessable object. Can you check that?

Comment: @Aeseir, I double checked, I am sure I set the right model to com.longz.ozssc.mac.generated.domain.nb.Firm (newer class) before I set view to my editFirm.jsp in my controller. "firm" is instance of class. I had removed all the old class from class path, and there is only one Firm Class in the class path, but my JSP is still point to the instance of old class (com.longz.ozssc.mac.generated.domain.Firm).

Comment: @BohuslavBurghardt, before I set view, I point my model to the newer class's instance firm in controller. Actually, it is same class only different is class package have to be changed, as business logic changing.

Comment: Ok so to clarify, issue is that model is filled in JSP and upon submission is binding to wrong object and thus doing something it shouldn't. if that is the case can you please paste in your POST handling code please?

Comment: Thank you for you guys help, I will have a individual some test project to test this issue again the what is the different. worst case is, I have to redo this part from scratch.

Comment: I had some update in main post, seems it is not a setting issue, most likely is a TomCat runtime error with object bundle.